# .+ not working as expected in a Google Analytics regex filter

Tags: regex, google-analytics

My website has the same news articles located at different root locations in the site. I want to create a roll-up report of the traffic to each article, regardless of where it appears on the site.

Since news is always in a folder called `/news`, I should just be able to write a regex that grabs anything after `/news` in the URI and replaces the URI field with that. However, articles are sometimes in two news folders, like this: `hostname.com/other-folder/news/news/article-name`

And there's my problem. My original regex includes the second "news" in the output when there are two in a row. That's what I want to stop.

This regex works well if there's only ever one `/news`:

```
(\/news)(\/?)(.*)
```

I'm grabbing the third capturing group.

I designed this new regex by poking around with regex101.com:

```
(.+\/news)(\/|$)(.*)
```

And regex101 indicates that it should work well, include all of `/news/news` in the first capturing group, and still give me what I need in the third capturing group.

However, when I implement it on my view, one `/news` is now ALWAYS included in the output URI. This is the opposite of the result I expected - to never see a `/news` in the output!

Switching `.*` for `.+` gets the behaviour I expect, though I don't understand why.

What am I missing? Could `.+` work differently in GA than in other regex implementations? Or am I just misunderstanding the difference between `.+` and `.*`?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is it you're trying to match ? `.*news(?:/(.*)|$)`

Comment: Or, this would work as well `news(?:/|$)([^/\r\n]*)$`

Comment: I'd like to match everything after the last `/news` in the string.

Comment: Do you have experience using `?:` in GA regexes? I'm not sure they'll allow that syntax. It's not in their documentation.

Comment: I prefer the second one. Give it a try.. If it's a primitive, backward company, use this `news(/|$)([^/\r\n]*)$` and group 2 contains it.

Comment: It's Google :) Though I guess Analytics is maybe a backwater of their product base these days. I switched it to `(.*\/news)(\/|$)(.*)` and that works... so it really does seem to be a quirk of how `.+` is interpreted, or maybe I don't understand the `+` operator as fully as I thought. I'll update the body text of this question accordingly.